# Seeking advice about plugin architecture frameworks for master's project

Tags: plugins, architecture

This past week I have been doing research into possible language/frameworks to use for a plugin architecture for my master's project. I feel as though I have learned a great deal, but I am still apprehensive in which direction I am comfortable going in.

Before summarizing my findings, I'd like to first describe the main requirements of my project--because I believe that it's possible that I've had tunnel vision on the implementation and maybe not on what the requirements call for itself.

My project is an IoT management platform, the idea is that the system will be comprised of services or modules, that provide communication, storage, security, events, device registration. Application developers will use these system services to create plugins to be loaded, unloaded as desired at runtime for end users to use with their devices.

I have done some tutorials with OSGI, some of which I had a lot of difficulty completing. I have read about plugin architecture implementations in C/C++ and golang, each seem to have their quirks and limitations.

Is using a plugin architecture for this project warranted? And if so, which framework/tools/language(s) would you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For architecture I think you should follow micro-service arch
and yes every language have their limitation then when you create service for high performance then use rust or c++ and when you want to create high performance api then create golang service and deploy them on cloud and kubernate.

For framework, if you still  confused what framework is suite you then follow clean architecture that will help you when create service
ex. you create golang service with gin framework you can switch to fiber framework very easy.

ref.
https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html
https://github.com/bxcodec/go-clean-arch